# Modal with image slideshow with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, modal-dialog, slideshow

Hi I am trying to implement a modal with slideshow for next images. I am using unsplash api to fetch images.

The problem I am facing is whenever I am trying to click a random image in a grid, it shows only the first image in Modal.

This is my implementation for setting up the images and modal functionality. I am using the react-modal package for setting up my Modal.

imageList = Array of objects containing image data

url = An object containing image url.

```
export default function Images({ imageList, url, id }) {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

    const length = imageList.length;

    function openModal() {
        setModalIsOpen(true);
    }
    function closeModal() {
        setModalIsOpen(false);
    }

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
    };

    const prevSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
    };

    if (!Array.isArray(imageList) || imageList.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <img onClick={openModal} key={id} src={url.urls.thumb} alt='' />
            <Modal
                ariaHideApp={false}
                closeTimeoutMS={200}
                style={customStyles}
                isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={closeModal}
                contentLabel='Image modal'
            >
                <AiOutlineArrowLeft
                    className='left-arrow'
                    onClick={prevSlide}
                />
                <AiOutlineArrowRight
                    className='right-arrow'
                    onClick={nextSlide}
                />
                {imageList.map((image, id) => {
                    return (
                        <div
                            className={
                                id === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'
                            }
                            key={id}
                        >
                            {id === current && (
                                <img
                                    alt=''
                                    className='image'
                                    src={image.urls.small}
                                />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the current-image-index by clicking the img.

```
<img onClick={()=>openModal(id)=} key={id} src={url.urls.thumb} alt='' />

function openModal(id) {
    setCurrent(id);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
}
```

or use the id / index from the props

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

set current by passing image id

```
<img onClick={()=>openModal(id)} key={id} src={url.urls.thumb} alt='' />

function openModal(id) {
    setCurrent(id);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
}
```

Comment: This is the deployed app: https://image-feed.vercel.app/

I tried your mentioned change, it didn't help.

Comment: Does you want image in modal on which you clicked ?

Comment: Yes. Right now, it is just showing the image which is at first index.

Comment: Do you set the index of the clicked image?

Comment: yes set currentImage when you click image and use it in slider

Comment: Yes I did, that helped to get the right image. Thanks a lot :)